# Views without any layout constraints may clip - using AutoresizingMask

Tags: macos, xcode-storyboard

I've been using a mix of LayoutConstraints and AutoresizingMask, where some simple view (NSViewController) would only be using autoresizing.

Since Xcode 10, some text objects, (or objects with intrinsic size such as NSButton, NSTextField-Label) seems to produce warning that seems to be requiring the use of Layout-Constraints: *"Views without any layout constraints may clip"*.

Answer (score 0):

Since this issue was not resolved as of today, I'll answer with a theory.

It seems that the logic is that any view, whose size is defined by its intrinsic size, (such as buttons and labels), is expected to use Layout-Constraints and cannot be done (in Storyboard at least) with AutoresizingMask alone.

A mixture of Layout-Constraints and AutoresizingMask is possible if the constraints objects are 'isolated' from the Autoresizing objects. Often, it's not possible and the whole view needs to be re-set with Layout-Constraints.